# Interface Method overriding

Tags: java, collections, overriding

> I need to know how I can override a method of an interface in java collection like ArrayList ? and can I do that inside my main class ?

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList is class not interface, if you want to override method of class you have just extends that class and override the method which you want. (Follow OOP syntax)